# WebRTC - Screen Sharing

Tags: javascript, webrtc, streaming, screensharing, simplewebrtc

While WebRTC prioritizes user privacy with screen selection prompts, you can't bypass them for automatic entire screen sharing.  Provide an informative message explaining automatic entire screen capture or offer manual selection options within your website to respect user control and avoid risky browser flag workarounds.

I have implemented screen sharing using the WebRTC API (getDisplayMedia). However, it prompts the user every time to select which screen (main, entire screen, etc.), whereas I want it to default to sharing the entire screen. When a user visits the URL, it should start sharing the entire screen directly. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: "When a user visits the URL, it should start sharing the entire screen directly. Is there any possibility to achieve this?" - No, and for good reason. It's a security risk. Imagine visiting a website, and that website starts covertly broadcasting whatever's on your screen, without your consent.